# How To Store localstorage Array Into MySQL Database?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, local-storage

I am currently using localstorage to store what pages the current user has visited:

```
<?php
//start the session 
session_start();
//set $username as the current logged in user
$username=$_SESSION["Username"];
?>
```

JQuery:

```
var journey = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('journey'))||[];
journey.push(location.protocol + 
'//' + location.host + location.pathname);
localStorage.setItem('journey', JSON.stringify(journey));
```

Currently this is a temporary storage, however I would also want to give them the option to save their journey.

How would I be able to save the individual URL's along with the user's ID (which is already stored in the database) into the MySQL database? e.g. table name 'Journey' with columns 'URL' and 'UserID'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MySQL journey table:

```
CREATE TABLE journey (
    userId INT NOT NULL,
    journeyUrl VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY( userId, journeyUrl ),
    FOREIGN KEY( userId ) REFERENCES userTable( userId )        
);
```

The insert journey Query:

```
$insert_query = "INSERT INTO journey ( userId, journeyUrl ) VALUES ( {$userId} , '{$journeyUrl}' );";
```

The update journey query if one already exists:

```
$update_query = "UPDATE journey SET journeyUrl = '{$journeyUrl}' WHERE userId = {$userId};";
```

Your php script would echo a result at the end where the result is a boolean. True means save was sucessful, False means saving was a failure:

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

You would have a php script that executes these queries based on whether or not there is a record in the table referencing the user already.

An jQuery AJAX function like so would call the script and save the journey:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",  
    url: "savejourney.php",  
    data: { id : userid, url : journeyUrl },
    dataType: "json", 
    success: function(data) {
        if(data) {
            alert("Journey saved sucessfully!");
        }
    }  
});
```

Comment: Where does the '$journeyUrl' variable in the PHP come from?

Comment: It could be passed along with the AJAX query, I forgot to add that in but it is edited to reflect that now.

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to do an Ajax call to a server for that. You'll need to make an Ajax request, you can do so using Jquery. You'd then need a server side language such as php to handle the request and do the insertions into the database.

There is an example of performing an AJAX call to a php file to insert into a database [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp). Just be aware that this is not the way you would do it in a production environment. However, it is a nice tutorial to understand the process.

**EDIT**

Based on your comment below I'll explain further. The example above does do what you want to. Currently your data is located in javascript on the "clients" machine. You want to transfer that to a mysql database.

To do this you're going to send the data using JQuery or Javascript. In the example they use Javascript in the `<script> </script>` tags located in the HTML section. This javascript code is used to send the data to php file which receives it at this line `$q=$_GET["q"];`The php function then inserts this data into a database.

In the example they use a `GET`to achieve this. You'll probably want to perform a `POST`request. It's worth your while to look up the [difference between the two](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html).

Comment: This tutorial is useful but it only shows how to send data using php/mysql to the html page, however I need to send it the other way: html/jquery to php/mysql.

Comment: @user1199649 I have updated my answer to reflect your comment.